# Identify ID of original feature and its surrounding buffer? ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, buffer, spatial-statistics

I have a set of **polygon** features, stored in geodatabase (ArcGIS 10.1 Desktop).  I want to create a **surrounding buffers**. I want further to be able to acknowledge the ID of original feature to ID of surrounding buffer. How can I make it?

I though the OBJECTID of original polygon equals OBJECTID of surrounding buffer. That's however not true, as my original data ID does not follow the sequence 0-N, but some numbers are excluded.

How can I make sure to identify the couple: original polygon + its buffer? It there any workaround, ideally in ModelBuilder?

[image]

Comment: From Help [10.3]: The output feature class will have a ORIG_FID field that contains the feature ID of the input feature for which the buffer was created. If a field named ORIG_FID exists in the input, its values will be overwritten in the output. If a Dissolve Type of All or List is used, the output will not have this field.

Comment: I did not applied Dissolve tool. Now, it seem tat you are right: I have the same ID values in the original + buffer files. Maybe my "repair geometry" at the end of script could produce the non identical OBJECTID?

Comment: You're never going to get the FID from both feature classes to match perfectly. You will have to use the ORIG_FID field in the buffer to identify its source feature.

Comment: ok, but how to add ORIG_FID to my buffer?

Comment: If it's not currently there, you will have to re-run the Buffer Tool with the appropriate settings to get the ORIG_FID

Comment: I have re-run the tool couple times and it seems to provide to the same ID for polygon and buffer (even after Repair geometry correction). I think my question is out-of date now. Thank you for your help @Bjorn !